# How to make persistent storage with docker-compose up-down-up?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a multiple container application, that is using the postgres image in docker-compose.yml file. Postgres container has volume on host machine for persistent storage.

When I run docker-compose up at first time all is fine, postgres creates db files in my host folder.
After it I need to shut down application temporarily with docker-compose down if I'll change code of web container.

When I run docker-compose up second time, postgres overwriting all db files, but I need that data not changes. How can I solve this issue?

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
      build: ./web
      command: python3 main.py
      volumes:
        - ./web:/app
      ports:
        - "80:80"  
      depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
      links:
        - db:db
        - redis:redis

    db:
      image: postgres
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"     
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD:0000
      volumes:
        - ./pgdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    redis:
      image: redis
      ports:
        - "6379:6379" 
      command: redis-server --appendonly yes  
      volumes:
        - ./redisdb:/data
```

Comment: I solve this problem. It occurs probably because I changed permissions  for _pgdb_ directory with host root user. By default I couldn't open _pgdb_ in host machine because owner  is _postgres_ user. 

I could be wrong but after I stopped to change the resolution of the problem was gone.

Comment: Add an Answer to your own post so that you can close it. Others might be interested in this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem. It occurs probably because I changed permissions for *pgdb* directory with host *root* user. By default I couldn't open *pgdb* in host machine because owner is *postgres* user. I could be wrong but after I stopped to change the resolutions the problem was gone.